# error if importing a 47G data file to IBM netezza database from Aginity workbench

Tags: sql, database, windows-7, netezza

I need to import a data txt file  (47 GB) to IBM netezza SQL database but I gor error:

```
 netezza database error HY000 error: 8 : data partition full
```

I work from IBM Aginity workbench on win 7.

The netezza server still have enough space.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your questions. i.e.-

> 1) "I work from IBM Aginity workbench on win 7" Ans = Aginity is not a
>   part of IBM, this product has no warranty from IBM though IBM suggest
>   to use this but not claims for any errors or crashes from this tool.
>
> 2) "The netezza server still have enough space" Ans = As far as i can
>   understand from your question is that you are accessing data on your
>   windows machine because NPS is built on RHEL6 and the error might be
>   through your win7 machine space. There is nothing to do with Netezza
>   space.

Workaround-

> Check if your windows machine has enough space (Not a preferred way).
>
> (Preferred way) You can download nz_client_windows/Linux from IBM partner website
>   (details can be followed from
>   "http://bajajvarun.blogspot.in/2014/02/install-netezza-client-on-ubuntu.html")
>   and then run following command -

```
nzsql -u <user_name> -pw <password> -db <database_name> -o <output_file_name> -host <NPS machine IP or domain_name> -c "<Query>"
```

Hope this will help.